# How to receive incoming json data posted from outside

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I want to receive json formatted posted data to my controller. Actually it's used for paypal payment webhook call issue. I already attached a json data example. Please advice me "FormCollection" is good idea to access that json or whats the best practice for this situation?

Json:

```
{"menu": {
  "id": "file",
  "value": "File",
  "popup": {
    "menuitem": [
      {"value": "New", "onclick": "CreateNewDoc()"},
      {"value": "Open", "onclick": "OpenDoc()"},
      {"value": "Close", "onclick": "CloseDoc()"}
    ]
  }
}}
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult ReceiveData(FormCollection data)
{
    using (var ctx = new db_mydb())
    {
    }

    return Json("ok");
}
```

Comment: Please, **never** use `FormCollection`. Use a ViewModel class instead, which you can generate using http://json2csharp.com/.

Comment: Viewmodel will work good to receive Json posted data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since that data being received is structured and comming in as JSON you should create strongly typed model(s) to store the data.

```
public class Menuitem {
    public string value { get; set; }
    public string onclick { get; set; }
}

public class Popup {
    public IList<Menuitem> menuitem { get; set; }
}

public class Menu {
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string value { get; set; }
    public Popup popup { get; set; }
}

public class PaypalWebhookModel {
    public Menu menu { get; set; }
}
```

Action should be updated to reflect the desired model.

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult ReceiveData([FromBody]PaypalWebhookModel data) {
    using (var ctx = new db_mydb()) {
        //...
    }
    return Json("ok");
}
```